# missing timezone offset when writing pandas dataframe to MSSQL datetimeoffset column

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, pymssql

The timezone offset is set to +00:00 for timestamp entries when writing pandas dataframe to a table on MSSQL database, although the timestamps in the dataframe contain CE(S)T offsets +02:00.

I am creating a simple table with three columns of which one contains datetime timezone aware timestamps. The said column datatype was set to datetimeoffset(7) when the table was created on the SQL server.

```
name = ['price']*24
values = np.random.rand(24)
starttimes = pd.date_range('2019-09-10 00:00', '2019-09-10 23:00', freq='h', tz='CET')

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': starttimes, 'values': values, 'item': name})

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')

df.to_sql(
    name='test_table',
    con=engine,
    index=False,
    if_exists='append',
    dtype={'start_time': DateTime(timezone=True)}
)
```

When the dataframe is inserted onto the table in the database, the offset becomes +00:00 instead of +02:00. 
For example, the original dataframe has an entry 
2019-09-10 00:00:00+02:00 
which on the server becomes 
2019-09-10 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00

The problem persists when I use pyodbc in place of pymssql for which i have a Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about pymssql, but with pyodbc you can insert to a `datetimeoffset` column if you convert the DataFrame column to string using `df.astype`:

```py
table_name = "test_table"
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(f"DROP TABLE [{table_name}]")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(f"CREATE TABLE [{table_name}] (dto datetimeoffset(7))")

dto = datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=2)))
df = pd.DataFrame([(dto,)], columns=['dto'])

# convert pandas Timestamp column to string
df = df.astype({'dto': numpy.str})

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

# check result
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(text(f"SELECT CAST(dto AS VARCHAR(50)) AS dto_str FROM [{table_name}]")).fetchall())
    # [('2019-09-10 00:00:00.0000000 +02:00',)]
```